# Filter Xml messages on element presence in Azure Topic

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, azure-queues

I have an Azure topic and want to filter messages on their XML elements.

```
<stay>
  ...
</stay>
```

vs

```
<flee>
  ...
</flee>
```

I have understood the SqlFilter is the way to go, but found no information on how to filter on the presens of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter messages based on the payload. SQL Filters work on headers / properties of the message, not message body. A potential way of achieving what you need is to stamp message headers with the appropriate information for SQL Filters to operate on. A few samples available in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples).